# Arduino - invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator^'

Tags: funções, arduino, operadores

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>

#define DHT1PIN 2
#define DHT2PIN 3
#define DHT3PIN 4
#define DHT4PIN 5
#define DHT5PIN 6
#define DHT6PIN 7

#define DHT1TYPE DHT11 // DHT 11
#define DHT2TYPE DHT11
#define DHT3TYPE DHT11
#define DHT4TYPE DHT11
#define DHT5TYPE DHT11
#define DHT6TYPE DHT11


DHT dht1(DHT1PIN, DHT1TYPE); 
DHT dht2(DHT2PIN, DHT2TYPE);
DHT dht3(DHT3PIN, DHT3TYPE);
DHT dht4(DHT4PIN, DHT4TYPE);
DHT dht5(DHT5PIN, DHT5TYPE);
DHT dht6(DHT6PIN, DHT6TYPE);

void setup();
void loop();

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("DHT11 + MPX5050DP");

  dht1.begin();
  dht2.begin();
  dht3.begin();
  dht4.begin();
  dht5.begin();
  dht6.begin();
}

void loop() {

  //MDPX5050 DP
  int reading = analogRead(1);
  float Pressure = 11.11 * reading - 2.2226;
  Serial.print(Pressure);

  float h1 = dht1.readHumidity();
  float t1 = dht1.readTemperature();

  float h2 = dht2.readHumidity();
  float t2 = dht2.readTemperature();

  float h3 = dht3.readHumidity();
  float t3 = dht3.readTemperature();

  float h4 = dht4.readHumidity();
  float t4 = dht4.readTemperature();

  float h5 = dht5.readHumidity();
  float t5 = dht5.readTemperature();

  float h6 = dht6.readHumidity();
  float t6 = dht6.readTemperature();


  if (isnan(t1) || isnan(h1)) {
  Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT #1");
  } else { 
    Serial.print("Humidity 1: "); 
    Serial.print(h1); 
    Serial.print(" %\t") ; 
    Serial.print("Temperature 1: "); 
    Serial.print(t1); 
    Serial.println(" *C");
   delay(1000);
  }


   if (isnan(t2) || isnan(h2)) { 
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT #2");
  } else { 
    Serial.print("Humidity 2: "); 
    Serial.print(h2);
    Serial.print(" %\t"); 
    Serial.print("Temperature 2: "); 
    Serial.print(t2); 
    Serial.println(" *C");
   delay(1000); 
  } 


   if (isnan(t3) || isnan(h3)) { 
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT #3");
  } else { 
    Serial.print("Humidity 3: "); 
    Serial.print(h3);
    Serial.print(" %\t"); 
    Serial.print("Temperature 3: "); 
    Serial.print(t3); 
    Serial.println(" *C");
   delay(1000); 
  } 


   if (isnan(t4) || isnan(h4)) { 
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT #4");
  } else { 
    Serial.print("Humidity 4: "); 
    Serial.print(h4);
    Serial.print(" %\t"); 
    Serial.print("Temperature 4: "); 
    Serial.print(t4); 
    Serial.println(" *C");
   delay(1000); 
  } 


   if (isnan(t5) || isnan(h5)) { 
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT #5");
  } else { 
    Serial.print("Humidity 5: "); 
    Serial.print(h5);
    Serial.print(" %\t"); 
    Serial.print("Temperature 5: "); 
    Serial.print(t5); 
    Serial.println(" *C");
   delay(1000); 
  } 

   if (isnan(t6) || isnan(h6)) { 
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT #6");
  } else { 
    Serial.print("Humidity 6: "); 
    Serial.print(h6);
    Serial.print(" %\t"); 
    Serial.print("Temperature 6: "); 
    Serial.print(t6); 
    Serial.println(" *C");
   delay(1000); 
  }




float tambiente,twb,Va,Entalpia_do_ar,Hv,Lv,Tpo,Pfi,x,Pb,Pa,Pv,Uabs,Vv,Hesp,c, Pvs;
//float tambiente2,twb2,Va2,Entalpia_do_ar2,Hv2,Lv2,Tpo2,Pfi2,x2,Pb2,Pa2,Pv2,Uabs2,Vv2,Hesp2,c2, Pvs2;
//float tambiente3,twb3,Va3,Entalpia_do_ar3,Hv3,Lv3,Tpo3,Pfi3,x3,Pb3,Pa3,Pv3,Uabs3,Vv3,Hesp3,c3, Pvs3;
//float tambiente4,twb4,Va4,Entalpia_do_ar4,Hv4,Lv4,Tpo4,Pfi4,x4,Pb4,Pa4,Pv4,Uabs4,Vv4,Hesp4,c4, Pvs4;
//float tambiente5,twb5,Va5,Entalpia_do_ar5,Hv5,Lv5,Tpo5,Pfi5,x5,Pb5,Pa5,Pv5,Uabs5,Vv5,Hesp5,c5, Pvs5;
//float tambiente6,twb6,Va6,Entalpia_do_ar6,Hv6,Lv6,Tpo6,Pfi6,x6,Pb6,Pa6,Pv6,Uabs6,Vv6,Hesp6,c6, Pvs6;


{   Serial.println ("Ponto 1");
    tambiente=t1+273.15;
  twb= t1*(atan[0.151977*(h1+8.313659)^0.5 ])+(atan(t1+h1))- (atan(h1-1.676331)+0.00391838*((h1)^3/2))*(atan(0.023101*h1)-4.686035);
  Entalpia_do_ar=1.01*t1;
  Lv=2538.2+2.91*t1;
  Hv=Lv+1,88*t1;
  Pfi=(1-3*(t1-twb)/(t1+18))*100;
  x=(-27405.526+97.5413*tambiente-0.146244*(tambiente*tambiente)+0.00012558*(tambiente*tambiente*tambiente)-0.000000048502*(tambiente*tambiente*tambiente*tambiente))/(4.34903*tambiente-0.0039381*tambiente*tambiente);
  Pvs=22105649.25*exp(x)/1000;
  Pv=Pfi*Pvs/100;
  Pa=101,325-Pv;
  Va=((287,05*(tambiente))/Pa)/1000;
  Uabs=0.6219*Pv/(Pb-Pv);
  Vv=(461,52*tambiente)/(Pv*100)/1000;
  Tpo=(31.685*log10(Pv*1000/613.34))/(1-0.1311*log10(Pv*1000/613.34));
  Hesp=4.1868*(0.24*t1+(597.3+0.441*t1)*Uabs);

  Serial.print("\n Volume Especifico Ar            =  %.3f    [m3/kg]"); Serial.print(Va);
  Serial.print("\n Volume Especifico Vapor         =  %.3f    [m3/kg]"); Serial.print(Vv);
  Serial.print("\n Entalpia do Ar                  =  %.2f    [kJ/kg]"); Serial.print(Entalpia_do_ar);
  Serial.print("\n Entalpia do Vapor               =  %.2f    [kJ/kg]"); Serial.print(Hv);
  Serial.print("\n Entalpia Especifica             =  %.2f    [kJ/kg]"); Serial.print(Hesp);
  Serial.print("\n Umidade Relativa                =  %.2f    [%]");     Serial.print(Pfi);
  Serial.print("\n Pressao de Vapor Saturado       =  %.2f    [KPa]");   Serial.print(Pvs);
  Serial.print("\n Pressao de Vapor                =  %.2f    [KPa]");   Serial.print(Pv);
  Serial.print("\n Pressao de Ar seco              =  %.2f    [Kpa]");   Serial.print(Pa);
  Serial.print("\n Umidade Absoluta                =  %.4f    [Kg/Kg]"); Serial.print(Uabs);
  Serial.print("\n Temperatura de Ponto de Orvalho =  %.1f    [C]");     Serial.print(Tpo); }
}
```

Aqui segue o código, ainda devo repeti-lo por ao menos 5 vezes, para 5 diferentes entradas de umidade e temperatura, estou certo que o problema se dá nesta equação.

```
twb= t1*(atan[0.151977*(h1+8.313659)^0.5 ])+(atan(t1+h1))- (atan(h1-1.676331)+0.00391838*((h1)^3/2))*(atan(0.023101*h1)-4.686035);
```

Porém não tenho ideia de como contorná-lo, alguem poderia me dar uma mão ?

Erros:

> error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator^'
>   error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'int' to binary 'operator^'

Comment: agradeço pela edição na formatação bfavaretto, estou me batendo aqui.

Comment: Você não estaria por acaso usando o operador ^ esperando que ele seja de potencia ou estaria? Digo isso por este operador ser um operador binário XOR no C/C++ e algumas outras linguagens.

Comment: era essa a intenção, exponencial... ouch, com o seu comentário, consultado a internet, vi a utilização de um tal 'pow ()' vou testar pra ver se supre minha necessidade, agradeço a contribuição.

Comment: `twb= t1*(atan[0.151977*variavel1])+(atan(t1+h1))- atan(h1-1.676331)+0.00391838*variavel2*(atan(0.023101*h1)-4.686035);`

'variavel1 = pow(h1+8.313659,0.5);`

`variavel2 = pow(h1,3/2);`

o erro retornado dessa vez esta sendo 'error: invalid types 'double ()(double)[double]' for array subscript'

Comment: Troque os parênteses retos por parênteses curvos.

Answer (score 1):

No Arduino você adiciona a biblioteca math.h para utilizar:

```
pow(base, expoente)
```

Utilize:

```
twb= t1*(atan(0.151977*pow(h1+8.313659, 0.5) )+(atan(t1+h1))- (atan(h1-1.676331)+0.00391838*(pow(h1, 3/2 ))*(atan(0.023101*h1)-4.686035);
```

**Depois do sinal de - (menos) tem que fechar o parenteses que é aberto antes do *atan*, senão também vai dar erro.**

C suporta conversão de tipos para executar a operação e depois a variavel (que recebeu o casting) volta ao tipo original:

```
float soma, num1;
int num2;

soma = num1 + (float) num2;
```

E se for utilizar essa formúla mais de uma vez, vale a pena transformar em função:

```
float twb( float a, float b ) {
  float primeiro = atan( 0.151977 * pow( b + 8.313659, 0.5 );
  float segundo = atan( b - 1.676331 ) + 0.00391838 * ( pow( b, 3/2 );
  float terceiro = atan( 0.023101 * b) - 4.686035) ;

  return ( a * primeiro + atan( a + b ) - segundo * terceiro );
}
```

Isso te ajudara quando precisar alterar alguma parte dela, automaticamente altera todas as vezes que a função é utilizada.

> Se a formula for muito grande divida ela, seja no meio do código ou em dentro de uma função, isso faz com que seja mais fácil de detectar erros.

Para utilizar:

```
twb( 7.0, 5.4);

twb( <primeiro numero>, <segundo numero> );
```